# Dask +Xarray implementation to handle multi year NetCDF Dataset

Tags: dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to work with two hydrological datasets (70 GB each) comprising of 66 years of simulated daily discharge and other variables. The datasets have netcdf files for each day.

I need to open both datasets together and If I try to open them using `xr.open_mfdataset`, it takes more than 1 hour to load.

I also tried using `xr.open_mfdataset('filename', parallel = True)` , but the time taken is almost same.

I also tried exporting the complete datasets individually into two large nc files so that I can open them again using chunk size parameter. But the operation kept on running for more than 2.5 hours and failed.

So, what is the best way to implement Dask xarray with multiple files?(how to define chunk size in case of multiple files).
I have currently referred to [this](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#reading-and-writing-data) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by implementing Dask Client on PBS cluster. I followed [this](https://blog.dask.org/2019/08/28/dask-on-summit) guide.